# Split the Dataset into parts to send in a request

Tags: scala, apache-spark, http, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have very big Dataset.

For example, the dataset looks like this:

```
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+
|   schema_from|          table_from|  column_from|link_type|schema_to|table_to|           column_to|
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|   ensure_sum|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|   ensure_sum|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|   ensure_sum|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...| ensure_value|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+
```

I convert such a dataset to json and send it in the body of an http request.
Everything is going well, but my server accepts a maximum of 10 MB of information.
And the dataset can be 15-20 MB. I can't send such large datasets. I need to split the dataset into pieces.

So here's what I have:

10mb = 10240kb х 1024 = 10 485 760 byte

Maximum size of one row from the dataset = 500 byte.

So I can send a maximum of one http request = 10 485 760 / 500 = 20 971 rows

And based on this information, I want an algorithm that will divide the dataset into parts so that the size of these parts does not exceed 20,000 rows.

When dividing, one more condition must be met.
The group from the column "column_to" must be located inside the same dataset.

For example dataset contain 4 group:

1. avg_ensure_sum_12m
2. avg_ensure_sum_3m
3. avg_ensure_sum_6m
4. avg_ensure_value_12m

Then the data sets will be divided approximately as follows.

first part:

```
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+
|   schema_from|          table_from|  column_from|link_type|schema_to|table_to|           column_to|
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|   ensure_sum|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|  avg_ensure_sum_12m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|   ensure_sum|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
|custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_3m|
```

second part:

```
    +--------------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+
    |   schema_from|          table_from|  column_from|link_type|schema_to|table_to|           column_to|
    +--------------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|   ensure_sum|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|   avg_ensure_sum_6m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm| indirect|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...| ensure_value|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|      inn_num|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
    |custom_cib_stg|p_overall_part_te...|protocol_dttm|   direct|  dbname1|  table1|avg_ensure_value_12m|
    +--------------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+
```

The most important condition is that one group is located in one dataset. Help to assemble a successful algorithm.

Comment: You can add a column to the dataset (called sentSuccessful) and flag it to true once request is successful and then filter just the columns that had that flag not set to true.

Answer (score 0):

So, i have put together a working solution.

```
case class DataLink(schema_from: String,
                    table_from: String,
                    column_from: String,
                    link_type: String,
                    schema_to: String,
                    table_to: String,
                    column_to: String)

val dataLinksDs  = targetDataLineage.dataLinks.repartition(col("column_to")).persist
  val targetGroups = dataLinksDs.groupBy("column_to")
                                .as[String, Long]
                                .count().collect().toMap
  val groupsDsList: List[Dataset[DataLink]] = splitDataset(dataLinksDs, targetGroups)
  groupsDsList.foreach(_.show())



private def splitDataset(ds: Dataset[DataLink], targetGroups: Map[String, Long]): List[Dataset[DataLink]] = {
  if (targetGroups.values.sum <= 20000 || targetGroups.size == 1)
    ds :: Nil
  else {
    val leftGroups  = targetGroups.take(targetGroups.size / 2)
    val rightGroups = targetGroups.takeRight(targetGroups.size - targetGroups.size / 2)
    splitDataset(ds.filter(col("column_to") isin (leftGroups.keys.toList:_*)),  leftGroups) ++
    splitDataset(ds.filter(col("column_to") isin (rightGroups.keys.toList:_*)), rightGroups)
  }
}
```